# Taking address of std::flush manipulator function not equal to previously stored address in static const variable

Tags: c++, static, stream, manipulators

I am developing a logger class that overloads the stream insertion operator.
I am having trouble catching the `std::flush` manipulator.

First, a quick summary of what I do:

Given an object of `LogClass`, I want to do the following:

```
LogClass logger;
logger << "Some text" << std::flush;
```

... and catch the `std::flush` manipulator.

All input is sent directly to an internal string stream for later logging by the following inlined operator (which works fine):

```
class LogClass
{
    // ...

    std::ostringstream m_internalStream;

    template <typename T>
    LogClass & operator<<(const T & rhs)
    {
        m_internalStream << rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    // ...
};
```

I am trying to catch the `std::flush` manipulator by overloading as follows (which also works fine):

```
LogClass & LogClass::operator<<(std::ostream & (*manip)(std::ostream &))
{
    std::ostream & (* const flushFunc)(std::ostream &) = std::flush;

    // Is the supplied manipulator the same as std::flush?
    if ((manip == flushFunc)) {
        flush(); // <-- member function of LogClass
    } else {
        manip(m_stream);
    }

    return *this;
}
```

The problem shows if I try to make the local variable `flushFunc` static, as follows:

```
static std::ostream & (* const flushFunc)(std::ostream &) = std::flush;
```

In this case, the value of the incoming `manip` pointer is *not* equal to `flushFunc`.

Why is that? Does it have anything to do with template instantiations of the `std::flush` function for `char`?

I am using MS Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

The problem also shows in this small working code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int, char **)
{
    static std::ostream & (* const staticFlushPtr)(std::ostream &) = std::flush;
    std::ostream & (* const stackFlushPtr)(std::ostream &) = std::flush;

    std::cout << std::hex <<
            "staticFlushPtr: " << (void *) staticFlushPtr << "\n"
            "stackFlushPtr: " << (void *) stackFlushPtr << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

... which gives this output on my machine:

```
staticFlushPtr: 013F1078
stackFlushPtr: 0FF10B30
```

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Rein A. Apeland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a definite bug in the compiler.  If there were
DLLs or such involved, I could understand it, or at least make
excuses, but in such a trivial example as your `main`...  (g++
gets it right.)

About all I can suggest is that you insert a filtering streambuf
in your output, which catches calls to `sync`.

Comment: I agree. Just compiled it on a MAC and on an online compiler ([link](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php)). Pointer values were equal in both cases.